# How to use URL output filter with multi-select TV?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have multi-select TV, and I have set URL output filter. I receive code like

```
<a title="title1" href="title1">Индия</a>
<br>
<a title="title2" href="title2">Тибет</a>
<br>
<a title="title2" href="title3">Мустанг</a>
```

Everything is OK, but I don't need the br tag, how to discard it?

Comment: Ничего непонятно, с таким знанием языка лучше спрашивать на ресурсах типа http://modx.pro/ - шансов что тебе помогут в разы больше.

Comment: Эммм... а что непонятного-то? есть TV с множественным выбором. Для него установлен фильтр вывода URL. Код получается с тегом br. Он мне не нужен, как сделать так, чтоб его не было?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First way to do it - create your own  [output type](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/template-variables/adding-a-custom-tv-output-type) based on url output type (core/model/modx/processors/element/tv/renders/web/output/url.class.php).

Second way - use [output modifier](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers)) "replace":

```
[[*my_urls_tv:replace=`<br>==`]]
```